# Why the if condition does not filtering the results?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, filtering

I want to create advance search filtering staff data according to certain criteria chosed by users. This application developed using laravel 5. I am querying the data using ajax function and if statement to filter the criteria. The results appear but it does not filter any condition in the if statement.

The controller of the filtering condition is this:

```
  public function kakitangan(Request $request)
  {
    $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
             ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan');

    if ($request->section != ""){
        $query->where('SectionID', $request->section);
    }

    $newitem = $query->get();

    return response::json($newitem);
  }
```

I also have tried this:

```
    $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
             ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan');

    if(request('section')) {
        $query->where('SectionID', request('section'));
    }
  $newitem = $query->get();

  return response::json($newitem);
```

But the result is the same..all data in itemregistrations appear in the output page. Although I select another section criteria.

This is the view page code for selection:

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::label('Seksyen', 'Seksyen') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::select('section', $sections, '', ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The selection id is from controller function:

```
     $sections = Section::pluck('sectionname', 'SectionID');
    //sent to html view
    return view('carian.index', compact('sections'));
```

Button to call ajax function to get the query:

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="cari">Cari</button>
```

The code for results appear:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#cari" ).click(function() {

        var seksyen = $("#section").val();
         $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('kakitangan') }}',
            data: {'section': seksyen},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#datatable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    }   
                $('#datatable tr').first().after(html);
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
      });
   </script>
```

Should be when the user select a section, only staffs of the section appear. But now all staffs appear when select any section.

I just tried to test whether the section value is correctly passed to the controller using this in controller:

```
    $try=$request->input('section');
    return response::json($try);
```

It results empty array..no value passed? Is it the section value is not passed correctly? How to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the section as a post param while you performing a GET request. 
Using jQuery you can send this as a query string using:

```
 var seksyen = $("#section").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('kakitangan') }}?' + $.param({'section': seksyen}),
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
```

In your controller you can also explicitly check if a request contains a query string using the `has` method on a request

```
if(request()->has('section')) {
    $query->where('SectionID', request('section'));
}
```

EDIT:

using the laravel collective Form helpers you can specific the field id using the following (note the fourth argument id)

```
{{ Form::select('section', $sections, '', ['id' => 'section', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
```

Comment: I tried to check #section value using    -->  $( "#cari" ).click(function() {
            alert($('#section').val()); but the popup says undefined. Is your answers can be used if the section value is not passed to ajax?

Comment: I had tried, it results no error but no value..maybe because it does not contain the section value.

Comment: Yes, the section has to exist before it can be passed to your backend. First make sure you can display the value in console or alert then pass it to your ajax call :)

Comment: why it cannot get the selection value?

Comment: Does your input field contain the id in the rendered HTML? post the rendered HTML of your select field in your question

Comment: yes, it has the id value when selected by users. I had edit my question

Comment: Check the updated answer you have to add the id to the form Form::select call

Comment: yes, you are right! It works very well..thank you for your help Ken!!